# How to parse value from wordpress $wpdb->get_results()?

Tags: php, wordpress

I am working on wordpress theme and failed to use arithmatics operation on wpdb->get_results().

If i write simple, then it update sucessfully in database

```
$sql = "SELECT room_count from " . BOOKYOURTRAVEL_ACCOMMODATION_VACANCIES_TABLE . " where accommodation_id = $accommodation_id";

    $result = $wpdb->get_results($sql) or die(mysql_error()); 


    $calc = $result;
```

But if I use minus operation with result it throws fatal error.

```
$sql = "SELECT room_count from " . BOOKYOURTRAVEL_ACCOMMODATION_VACANCIES_TABLE . " where accommodation_id = $accommodation_id";

    $result = $wpdb->get_results($sql) or die(mysql_error()); 


    $calc = $result - 1;
```

Error

```
Fatal error: Unsupported operand types in C:\xampp\htdocs\beta\wp-content\themes\byt-child\includes\post_types\accommodations.php on line 1199
```

Freinds please suggest me how to resolve this. I have used result->room_count -1 but stucked on result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are expecting a single result field, you should use get_var

```
$sql = "SELECT room_count from " . BOOKYOURTRAVEL_ACCOMMODATION_VACANCIES_TABLE . " where accommodation_id = $accommodation_id";

$result = $wpdb->get_var($sql); 

if( $result ) {
    $calc = $result - 1;
}
```

Comment: Thanks sir, what is case of multi value

Comment: Then you should loop trough it, get_results returns an array of items, which you can walk trough with `foreach($results AS $result) { }`

Comment: $wpdb->get_var () will return multiple values to $result ? supporse database have multi rows with same id then $result will have all room_count value in it, or we have to replace $wpdb->get_var()

Comment: You have to use get_results with a foreach loop, see my comment aboven.